# Parallelism inside sequential loop with JAX

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, jax

How is the following data-location parallelism translated to a per-device implementation with collective communication using `jax`?

```
import os

os.environ["XLA_FLAGS"] = (
    f'--xla_force_host_platform_device_count=8'
)

import functools as ft
import jax as jx
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.random as jrn
import jax.lax as jlx
import jax.experimental.mesh_utils as jxm
import jax.sharding as jsh

# Create a sharding to distribute across devices
devices = jxm.create_device_mesh((8,))
sharding = jsh.PositionalSharding(devices)

@ft.partial(jx.jit,  static_argnums=0, out_shardings=sharding.reshape(8, 1))
def test(m):
    
    # Generate random dense operator that respects output sharding 
    key = jrn.PRNGKey(0)
    J = jrn.uniform(
        key=key,
        shape=(m, m),
        dtype='f8',
        minval=-0.1,
        maxval=+0.1)
    J = 0.1*J+jnp.eye(m, m, dtype='f8')

    # Generate random initial state that respects output sharding
    y = jrn.uniform(
        key=key,
        shape=(m, 1),
        dtype='f8',
        minval=+0.0,
        maxval=+1.0)
    
    def calc_body(y, i):
        return y+1.0e-06*J @ y, None
    y, empty = jlx.scan(calc_body, y, None, length=1000)
    
    return y

test_comp = test.lower(2**14).compile()
y = test_comp()
jx.debug.visualize_array_sharding(y)

+---+
+ 0 +
+---+
  . 
  . 
  . 
+---+
+ 8 +
+---+
```

For memory complexity reasons, and use of a carry, the outer loop is performed using `jax.lax.scan`.

From my understanding, making the parallel execution explicit inside `jax.lax.scan`, with `jax.pmap` then `jax.lax.psum` for example, will lead to unnecessary recompilation and gathers, especially if the outer `test` function is also compiled.